# Can't see my DB on Microsoft SQL Server Management

Tags: c#, sql, .net, code-first

I'm creating two different DBs with a code-first approach on .NET.

While they are both created successfully, when I go to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I can see only one of them.

This creates the DB that does show up:

```
public class MappingContextGeneral : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SuperUser> SuperUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InfoLogin> PassWordSuperUsers { get; set; }
    public MappingContextGeneral()
       : base("CheBayDB")
    {
    }
}
```

This one creates the DB that the SQL Server Management Studio isn't showing:

```
public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
public DbSet<InfoLoginClient> PassWordsClients { get; set; }
public DbSet<InfoLoginAdmin> PassWordsAdmins { get; set; }
public MappingContextStoreRelacional(string store_name)
    : base(store_name)
{
}
```

They look really similar and my team is using the same code without problems, so I think it's a problem with Management Studio or SQL Server.

My `app.conf` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework"         type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,         EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory     type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory,     EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"     type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,     EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Why doesn't the second one show up on SQL Server Management ?

Comment: What is the default constructor for the second content? Do you have a CheBayDb connectionstring and a similar one for the second one in your app.config/web.config?

Comment: I was more hoping for the part with the [connection strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756(v=vs.100).aspx) in it. These sections you show here are the same for everyone in the world...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a connection string for one of then that maps to a local instance of Sql Server. For the other one I guess that you don't have a connection string or that the connection string is a local db database.

Check in web.config or app.config.